# Tapping the cell selections does not change the cell accessory to a checkmark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Can someone help me? I've been following along with Apple's official Objective C tutorial (the one that has us create a To Do List).

I'm stuck at the part where tapping the cell item displays/removes a checkmark. It's not happening.

Here's my implementation file if someone could take a look?

I've really tried my best to solve where I went wrong. I swear I tried my best to figure out everything on my own before posting here. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

EDIT: So i put a breakpoint in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. It was not triggered when I tapped a table item, so it's not getting called when I tap items, right? Where do I look next?

```
//
//  ToDoListTableViewController.m
//  ToDoList
//
//  Created by Kevin Zagala on 9/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Kevin Zagala. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ToDoListTableViewController.h"
#import "ToDoItem.h"


@interface ToDoListTableViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

@implementation ToDoListTableViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
}

- (void)loadInitialData {

    ToDoItem *item1 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item1.itemName = @"Buy milk";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
    ToDoItem *item2 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item2.itemName = @"Buy eggs";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item2];
    ToDoItem *item3 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item3.itemName = @"Read a book";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item3];

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self loadInitialData];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.toDoItems count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;

    if (toDoItem.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    ToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}

@end
```

Comment: try reloading whole tableview instead of reloading a single row in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Shan how do i do that? i'm pretty new to objective c programming, if you couldn't tell. :)

Comment: i posted an answer check it

Comment: i have updated my code once check it,its working fro me..

Comment: add NSLog to cell for row to check value of tappedItem.completed

Comment: Good news is: Your code is fine. Bad news is: The error has to be somewhere else. Set a breakpoint in your `cellForRow` method and check a) if it gets called and b) what the values of your todo item are.

Comment: Hi All, so i put a breakpoint in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. It was not triggered when I tapped a table item, so obviously it's not getting called... Where do I look next?

Comment: I have encounterd the similar problem, when I clicked item 1, sometimes no response, sometimes the item2 responsed.  what happened? have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't help. After changing the if/else statement to what you have suggested, what I am seeing now is the checkmark being displayed, but not leaving when tapped. 

Is there something I can change in interface builder, or maybe one of the other project files, that can help with this?

Comment: Still didn't work. Hmm... On a side note, when i call the initial load function and set an item with .completed set to TRUE, there is a checkmark that gets displayed. However, it's still not responding to taps... As in, it won't disappear if tapped, and re-appear if not showing.

Comment: in the code what i have posted there is no relation between cell accessory type and .completed

Answer (score 0):

try reloading whole tableview,

what u are doing should work, i tested your code by putting a dummy object with boolean value, it worked for me,

Note Both reloading the whole tableview and reloading the selected cell will work, only u are setting the correct boolean value

```
 - (void)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
   ToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
//   [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; //comment this
    [tableView reloadData]; //add this 
}
```

Comment: Hi Shan, that didn't work for me. Thanks though. I think its something else that I set incorrectly... ugh... Again, thanks though.

Comment: put a break point at the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and check completed flag of toDoItem is set or not, what u are doing should work, if u set the boolean value of complete of toDoItem

Comment: break point fires when first loaded but does not when item is clicked